# Leetcode Three Sum in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, k-sum

Here's my solution for the Leet Code's Three Sum problem -- would love feedback on (1) code efficiency and (2) style/formatting. This is Python 3.

Problem:

> Given an array nums of n integers, are there elements a, b, c in nums
>   such that a + b + c = 0? Find all unique triplets in the array which
>   gives the sum of zero.
>
> Note:
>
> The solution set must not contain duplicate triplets.
>
> Example:
>
> Given array nums = [-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -4],
>
> A solution set is: [   [-1, 0, 1],   [-1, -1, 2] ]

My solution:

```
def threeSum(nums):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :rtype: List[List[int]]
    """

    def _twoSum(nums_small, target):
        '''
        INPUT: List of numeric values, int target 
        OUTPUT: list: pair(s) from nums_small that add up to target and -1*target
        '''
        nums_dict = {}
        return_lst = []

        for indx, val in enumerate(nums_small, target):
            if target - val in nums_dict: 
                return_lst.append([val, target - val, -1*target]) 
            nums_dict[val] = indx
        return return_lst 

    return_dict = {}

    for indx, val in enumerate(nums):
        for solution in _twoSum(nums[:indx] + nums[indx+1:], -1*val):
            if sorted(solution) not in return_dict.values():
                return_dict[str(indx)+str(solution)] = sorted(solution) # ... hacky way of storing multiple solutions to one index ...

    return list(return_dict.values())
```

Comment: What Python version did you write this for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Code

> "When all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail."

Your tool chest seems to have `dict`, which you are using to implement a container which doesn't contain any duplicates.  There is a name for that tool.  It is called as `set`.  Study it; you will find it very useful.

Consider:

```
    nums_dict = {}

    for indx, val in enumerate(nums_small, target):
        if target - val in nums_dict: 
            pass 
        nums_dict[val] = indx
```

You are never **using** the value `indx`; you are just storing it and never retrieving it.  You could just as easily write:

```
    nums_dict = {}

    for val in nums_small:
        if target - val in nums_dict: 
            pass 
        nums_dict[val] = True
```

which avoids the `enumerate()`, with the odd initial value, and the indices which did nothing.  But this is still storing the values `True`, and never retrieving them.  You don't need to do this, if you use a set:

```
    nums_dict = set()

    for val in nums_small:
        if target - val in nums_dict: 
            pass 
        nums_dict.add(val)
```

You again use a `dict` for `return_dict` to ensure you don't have any duplicate solutions.  Actually, this code is a worse that the former, because you are using `in return_dict.values()`, so instead of an \$O(1)\$ key lookup, you're doing an \$O(n)\$ search through the entire list of values!  If that wasn't bad enough, you are sorting solutions twice: once to see if they already exist in `return_dict`, and a second time to add it into the dictionary if it wasn't found.  Saving the sorted solution would avoid the second sort.

You could replace `return_dict` with a `set` as well, but there is a catch, you can't add a `list` into a `set`, because the items in a `set` must be hashable to a constant value but lists are unhashable (because they can be mutated).  You can get around this by using tuples, which can't be mutated, so they can be hashed.

```
 return_dict = set()

 for index, val in ...:
    for solution in ...:
        sorted_solution = tuple(sorted(solution))
        return_dict.add(sorted_solution)

 return list(return_dict)
```

The above returns a list of tuples.  If you need a list of lists, that can be easily obtained as well, using list comprehension ...

```
 return [ list(solution) for solution in return_dict ]
```

... which is another useful tool for your tool chest.

---

### Algorithm

Using `_twoSum()` to solve the `threeSum()` problem is good reuse of code.  Kudos.

However, looping over all indices and for each index, constructing a new list omitting just that one value from the list `nums[:indx] + nums[indx+1:]` is extremely inefficient.

Since "Leetcode" is a puzzle solving site, I won't give you the better algorithm, but I will say that splitting `nums` into `len(nums)` different lists is not the way to go.  I would split it into 2 lists, or maybe 3 lists tops.  Good luck!

Comment: It took me a while to realize that you are talking about a dictionary (`dict`) when saying `map` and not the built-in function `map`...

Comment: @Graipher The dangers of too many languages, and RUI.  Fixed.

Comment: Ah, thanks for reminders on tuples @AJNeufeld